# Create Webpage like Windows 8 Start Screen (Newbie)

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, web-applications, windows-8

First, I am a high-schooler and a very new programmer (think CS101 level).  In my free time (sadly limited), I want to try some project to encourage me to learn more, and I have an interesting idea.

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask, but I'm wondering if anyone could get me pointed in the right direction.  I want to make a web site that looks similar to the Windows 8 Start Screen (here is a [link to an image](http://compixels.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/Windows-8-Start-Screen.jpg), if, for some reason, you don't know what it looks like).

The idea is have similar block-like objects of varying lengths (maybe not as neat of a grid as Windows 8 has) that one can scroll though horizontally, and that can have some "active" things on them.  Clicking on one could use some AJAX techniques to either change to another menu, or open an information window on the page.  Kind of like how Outlook/Hotmail can change screens without reloading.  The information for the box items would probably come from a database.

I have a small amount of experience in PHP, MySQL, and JavaScript - enough to understand some code and write simple scripts.  What should I focus on learning for my idea of a project?  I'm just looking for a roadmap of things to study.

Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not a great place for the question as it is because it is too open ended. Stack overflow is about technical questions where you show your code and get help on why something isn't working. It will be when you have specific questions like: "Should I use a table to display blocks of varying lengths like windows 8", or "This rollover effect doesn't work how I want it".

Comment: @JuanMendes I thought this was the case, but I wasn't sure of a better place.  Super User doesn't seem to be much about programming, and the "Programmers" site is for professionals.  And I didn't really want to go to Yahoo! Answers...

Comment: You could try http://jacedc.deviantart.com/#/d5oqhvq but its unfinished and contains no responsive designing. Also browser behavior varies dramatically, but it is still an unfinished project. (P.S. Sorry for being a little late, just thought I'd throw that out there :P)

Comment: @ModernDesigner That is interesting, but my project has evolved into more of a horizontal scrolling timeline app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can mock up the win8 look with css and 2 image widths and whether its a normal or wide item just add the extra class to the style. With jQuery you can make the icons/page drag-able ect, with a bit of work you could simply measure the width and load more content via ajax much like lazy load but horizontal, use the `ondblclick=""` to initiate loading of the app/content, this is what I come up with in 30min. [Source & images](https://www.dropbox.com/s/i9504cs9a0b12bk/win8.rar)

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>basic win8</title>
<style>
*{font-family: "Segoe UI", Frutiger, "Frutiger Linotype";}
body{background-image:url('Win8Background.jpg');}

#wrapper {
    width: 70%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-left:auto;
     margin-right:auto;
}
.sortable-list li {
    padding: 4px;
    margin: 4px;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid black;
    list-style-image: none;
    list-style: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color:#204558;
}

#dashboard-layout .item.normal {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

#dashboard-layout .item.wide {
    width: 224px;
    height: 100px;
}

.item.normal p{
margin:0px;
padding: 0px;
}

.item.wide p{
margin:0px;
padding: 0px;
}

h1{color:white;}

#left_head{width:45%; float:left;}
#right_head{width:45%; float:right; text-align:right;margin-right:15px;}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function update_columns() {
    var positions = []
    $("#dashboard-layout .item").each(function() {
        var $item = $(this);
        positions.push($item.attr('id'));
    });
    $.post("./", { 'positions[]': positions },
        function(data) {
            alert("Update Success - New positions:" + positions);
        }
    );
}

$(function() {
    $("ul.sortable-list").sortable({
        connectWith: "#wrapper",
        placeholder: 'ui-state-highlight',
        tolerance: 'pointer',
        revert: true,
        forcePlaceholderSize: true,
        forceHelperSize: true,
        update: update_columns,
    }).disableSelection();
});
</script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="left_head"><h1>Start</h1></div>
<div id="right_head"><h1>Lawrence Cherone</h1></div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>

<div id="wrapper">

<ul class="sortable-list" id="dashboard-layout">

    <li id="a" ondblclick="" class="item normal" style="background-image:url(xbox.png); background-size:110px">
    content a
    </li>

    <li id="b" ondblclick="" class="item normal" style="background-image:url(xbox.png); background-size:110px">
    content b
    </li>

    <li id="c" ondblclick="" class="item wide" style="background-image:url(photos.png); background-size:224px">
    content c
    </li>

    <li id="d" ondblclick="" class="item wide" style="background-image:url(photos.png); background-size:224px">
    content d
    </li>

    <li id="e" ondblclick="" class="item wide" style="background-image:url(photos.png); background-size:224px">
    content e
    </li>

    <li id="f" ondblclick="" class="item normal" style="background-image:url(xbox.png); background-size:110px">
    content f
    </li>

    <li id="g" ondblclick="" class="item normal" style="background-image:url(xbox.png); background-size:110px">
    content g
    </li>

    <li id="h" ondblclick="" class="item wide" style="background-image:url(photos.png); background-size:224px">
    content h
    </li>

    <li id="i" ondblclick="" class="item wide" style="background-image:url(photos.png); background-size:224px">
    content i
    </li>

    <li id="j" ondblclick="" class="item normal" style="background-image:url(xbox.png); background-size:110px">
    content j
    </li>

    <li id="k" ondblclick="" class="item wide" style="background-image:url(photos.png); background-size:224px">
    content k
    </li>
</ul>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the time you spent!  I thought I was going in the right direction with jQuery, but was not totally sure.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming each "Block" on your site represents a single row in a database (Meaning no inherited parent-child relationship) it'be pretty easy to simply use CSS3 to create the blocks, jQuery to do the roll-over effects (And hovers, because let's face it, moving fish are awesome).

Integrating jQuery and Ajax will allow you to do the database call either by PHP as a flat file or OOP.

Might also want to look into nested queries as they'll most likely come in handy if you wanted to do something crazy like have 2 "Blocks" on the one page and you need to get data from 2+ tables onto said page.

Good luck

Comment: "do the database call either by PHP as a flat file or OOP."  I have read some about using a separate .php file to query the database, but what are you talking about with "OOP"?  I'm assuming you mean Object-oriented programming, but not sure how it is applied in this case, or different from the techniques used here: http://openenergymonitor.org/emon/node/107

Comment: Flat File =

<Code code code code>
require_once('File.php') <--- contains process for logic etc
<code code code>

OOP Method:

require_once('DBCon.php);
require_once('DBQueries.php);
require_once('Application-Blocks.php');

And each of those files pretains to multiple functions so that when it comes time to change the "Web Page" you only need to run a few simple lines such as 

$dbConn = new dbConn();
$dbConn->dbConnect();
$dbConn->dbQueries->loadAppConfig();

Extremely rough but hopefully you'll get the idea. Using OOP allows you to create prepared functions, accessible almost anywhere.